# How to enable lower CPU idle frequencies

Tags: cpu, speed, cooling

Working with a a10-7850K, it just kicks off heat.  In order to reduce power use and fan noise, how would I go about configuring a lower idle for the CPU?  I know the host OS has a role in configuring frequency, but I'm not sure what its role is in setting the minimum frequency.

Currently working on ArchLinux

Comment: I think the OS take as much CPU, as it need. So if you still producing a lot of heat, maybe some processes still running on other threads (virus maybe).

Comment: No, I'm running ArchLinux and am pretty good about monitoring the system.  A few daemons running in the background that I want there and the frequency does drop from 3.7 GHz to 1.7 GHz when not under load.  I'm looking for a way to change that 1.7 GHz down to sub GHz levels.

Comment: You really should update your question to indicate what operating system your using and what exact goals you want to achieve.

Comment: Googling for 'linux cpu frequency', even the *first* hit I got was [on Arch's own wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/CPU_frequency_scaling). What have you done to try to answer your question yourself? We're happy to help you out if you get stuck, but we expect you to try for yourself first.

Comment: It does not cover how to lower the default idle speed.  I've been there.